# image roller over and hover

Tags: html, css

So, I'm supposed to modify my HTML and CSS file to allow for the image to roll over to a different image once the user hovers over it with the cursor. This is my HTML code that has my picture. I'm not exactly sure how to make the image roll over to another image of my choice.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 850px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid #931420;
  background-color: #fffded;
}

a:focus,
a:hover {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <h1>An Image Rollover Using Background Images</h1>
    <img src="../images/sampson_dinosaur.jpg" alt="Scott Sampson 
           with dinosaur">
</section>
```

Comment: where is your css?

Comment: body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #931420;
    background-color: #fffded;
}
a:focus, a:hover {
 font-style: italic;
}

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the image in another tag, say an `<a>`, and use `:hover` to show/hide the image based on hover status of the `<a>`:

```css
.image-swap {
  display: inline-block;
}

a .on_hover {
  display: none;
}

a:hover .on_hover {
  display: block;
}

a:hover .off_hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <h1>An Image Rollover Using Background Images</h1>
    <a class="image-swap">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200/" alt="Scott Sampson 
     with dinosaur" class="off_hover">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Scott Sampson 
     with dinosaur" class="on_hover">
     </a>
</section>
```